# Is trace formula always valid for determining eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, trace

As far from textbook I heard about this formula for calculating eigenvalues of a square matrix:

- **det(M)=$\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3 ....$**
- **Tr(M)=$\sum_i \lambda_i $**

Ok I have no doubt about the determinant formula. But I have some confusion about the trace formula as it does not hold always. Whenever the trace changes due to matrix operations I can not decide which trace to use and which I should not. Take this example-

[image]

Normally the trace formula is working here. Ok fine. But if I do some matrix operation (like $C_3=C_3-C_2$), the trace changes (from $12$ to $13$). And I can not use the formula anymore.

My question is how do I know if the formula will work or not?

Comment: The formula holds. Matrix row / column operations do not conserve the trace.

Comment: Two matrices that are similar have the same trace, since $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC)=\operatorname{Tr}(BCA)$ for all $A,B,C\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: @user376343 No it doesn't. Eigen values are 5, 5, 2. Sum of them is 12 & not 13. But that column operation gives 13.

Comment: The trace formula is a relation between the trace and the eigenvalues, and it always holds. The point is that the eigenvalues themselves are not preserved by row/column operations. For example, any invertible matrix can be brought to the identity using row/column operations, that does not mean every invertible matrix has eigenvalue $1$. The eigenvalues are changing, so of course the trace is changing as well, but the trace relation between the two hold at every step.

Comment: @EuYu ...... that means eigen values of a matrix are not constants? I haven't heard that before. Can you please provide me some extra information or any link...

Comment: @ArnabMaitiMAS I don't know what you mean by "constants". Constant with respect to what? Eigenvalues are invariants up to matrix similarity, i.e., $A \mapsto PAP^{-1}$. Row and column operations do not preserve matrix similarity, so there's no reason for them to preserve the eigenvalues.

Comment: @EuYu  Ok I got it. That means if in a problem it is said to find out eigenvalues I should not do any matrix operations. Thank you very much.

Comment: No. You can do matrix operations, but if you do a column operation you have to also do the reverse operation on the rows. For example if you do $C_3:=C_3-C_2$ you must also do $R_3:=R_3+R_2$.